# python error about declaration list and assignment value at the list

Tags: python

```
a=[['']*2]*2
a[0][1]='previous'    
a[1][1]='new'
print(a[0][1])
```

The result of this code is 'new' instead of 'previous'.
When I changed the declaration of list as
a=[ [[''],['']], [[''],['']] ]
now it is okay.
But why difference?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's assume a == b.
Multiplying a list by (case a) 2 creates a deep copy, i.e. memory addresses are shared.
Constructing a list by hand (case b) avoids this issue.
Hence when you access and updates elements within a you are actually updating both inner lists:

```
a = [['']*2]*2
b = [['', ''], ['', '']]
    
print(a == b) # True

print(a)
a[0][1] = 'previous'
print(a)
print(id(a[0]) == id(a[1])) # True, same memory address

print(b)
b[0][1] = 'previous'
print(b)
print(id(b[0]) == id(b[1])) # False, different memory addresses
```

Comment: That’s true, but does it explain the different behavior for assignment?

Comment: See the edited answer, let me know if you need clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[['']*2]*2
```

above can be broken down into:

```
a = ['']*2 #result: a = ['', ''] --> it copies value of '' since '' is a string
a = [a]*2 #result: a = [a,a] --> which means it copies the reference of a instead of its value since a is a list.

a[0][1]='previous'   # result: [['', 'previous'], ['', 'previous']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [['']*2]*2
print (a[0][1] is a[1][1]) # true
```

So when you declare an array, the element in array should be different reference object.

Ref: [Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)

Answer (score 0):

1. With a=[''*2] you will get ['']   because empty string * 2 = empty string
2. With a=['']*2 you will get ['','']
3. With a=[['']*2] you will get [['','']]
4. With a=[['']*2]*2 you will get  [['', ''], ['', '']]   Similar to step 2

What you used was a=[['']*2]*2   -->    [['', ''], ['', '']]
What you should have used was a = [[['']]*2]*2  -->  [[[''], ['']], [[''], ['']]]